# Python not resizing height of an image

Tags: python, image, image-resizing

I want to resize some images and here is my code.

```
import os
from PIL import Image

size = 300, 300

for f in os.listdir('.'):
    if f.endswith('.png'):
        i = Image.open(f)
        fn, fext = os.path.splitext(f)
        i.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
        i.save('output/{}{}'.format(fn, fext))
```

The code is working fine and it resizes all my image to a width of 300px, but the height did not resize.

Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Image.thumbnail()` is designed to keep the aspect ratio of the original image. If you want the output image to be exactly 300x300 px, use `Image.resize()` instead.

Comment: hello Rob , thanks for answer I used resize() like you said, but it didnt work  out it even didnt resize the width  any idea plz ?

Comment: `thumbnail` is an inplace method, but `resize` returns a copy of the resized Image. So change the line with thumbnail to `i = i.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)`.